# Using CLists in c++ -Could not understand

Tags: c++, mfc

I searched for a sample program to work on with the CList.But i could not find it.I got some basic definitions about the CLists(template class that behaves similar to the doubly linked lists).. and is used to store the aggregate data..The 1st argument is stored internally by the list..I could not see what elements are stored in the list and how to retrieve it.

```
RsData Data; //object of class RsData
RsEvent* Event;//pointer to class RsEvent
CList<Event*,Event*>  EventQueue;
Data.EventQueue.RemoveAll(); 
//removing the attributes and methods of the class RsEvent stored in the list.
```

Comment: Where does this CList class come from?  Perhaps you could provide an example that compiles?

Comment: in afxtempl.h ... template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE = const TYPE&> class CList : public CObject { protected: struct CNode { CNode* pNext; CNode* pPrev; TYPE data; }; stmts; };

Comment: Why do you not considering `std::list`? It is described in the Stroustroup's book "The C++ Programming Language" and in the books on the STL, it is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the doc is [CList on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxde0zae%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

And there is a link there for the [COLLECT Sample: Illustrates MFC Collection Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw2702d6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I'm not sure how this doc was not found, so perhaps your question needs to be clarrified.

The list offers front/back inserting and looking, aswell as methods for iterating.

```
// Define myList.
CList<CString,CString&> myList;

// Add an element to the front of the list.
myList.AddHead(CString("ABC"));

// Verify the element was added to the front of the list.
ASSERT(CString("ABC") == myList.GetHead());
```

Comment: Hi i did as you have given here ....#include "stdafx.h" #include "afxtempl.h" #include <iostream> #define _AFXDLL using namespace std; int main() { CList<CString,CString&> myList; myList.AddHead((CString("ABC"))); ASSERT((CString("ABC")==myList.GetHead())); return 0; } output:getting compiler error that  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]...

Comment: Your lack of knowledge is currently beyond my help

Comment: @Beata - The message tells you what's wrong! You have to choose the same versions of MFC and CRT, either both as DLLs or both as static libraries.

Comment: I'm new to this MFC and i could not understand what the error is.so i included the #define _AFXDLL as mentioned in the error..But again i got the same error..sorry to bother you both with my little knowledge.I will check how to choose the same versions of MFC and CRT as DLLs..